# Hide Bars On Tap with only a bottom toolbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uitoolbar, xcode-storyboard

When you drag a `UINavigationController` into a storyboard, you can enable the Hide Bars On Tap option which will hide/show the navigation bar and toolbar upon tapping anywhere in the `UIView`. This works well except in the case where you don't have a navigation bar and you only have a toolbar. (You checked Shows Toolbar but not Shows Navigation Bar.) When you launch the app there is no visible navigation bar but when you tap a navigation bar slides down from the top, then if you tap again both bars slide away.

How can you use Hide Bars On Tap with only a toolbar and prevent a navigation bar from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

You can get hold of the gesture recognizer via the barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer property.Then you add actions to this gestureRecognizer to do whatever you want.
In your case ,this snippet will work:`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true

   navigationController?.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "tap:")}


func tap(gest: UIGestureRecognizer){
    navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
}
```